# How to fix strange conversion from String.ToUpper() in C#

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'm trying to show something like "contáctenos" in uppercase, but when I use the string.toUpper() method I have the strange result "CONTáCTENOS" instead of "CONTÁCTENOS".

The  page "culture" is set correctly to "es-ES" and the "uiculture" too.
How can I obtain the correct result if it's possible, without using regex or replace.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
.ToUpper(new CultureInfo("es-ES", false));
```

reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24kc78ka.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The `string.ToUpper()` function uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, not the page's specific culture or the `CurrentUICulture`. You can pass the page's `CultureInfo` into the `ToUpper` function and this should properly transform your string.

Comment: Both CultureInfo.CurrentCulture and Page.Culture uses Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture. String.ToUpper() uses CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, so I presume he hasn't set any culture information at all.